# Suddenly getting "Target class [Inertia\Ssr\Gateway] does not exist." I don't use Inertia's SSR. How can I get back to a functioning site?

Tags: laravel, inertiajs, laravel-jetstream

I've got a Laravel Jetstream project using Inertia.  I've been running it for a while.  Launched on Jetstream v1, later upgraded to v2. Everything has been running great.  Today I was messing with some composer and npm stuff and suddenly every page is broken.  I just get an error that looks like this:

Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [Inertia\Ssr\Gateway] does not exist.

This happens on every view. I have never used Inertia's SSR, and I don't want to (at least not currently).  I tried resetting both my composer json files and my npm json files but I cannot get back to my functioning site.  I'm losing my mind.  Any ideas of how I can get back to my original functioning site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove vendor folder and node_modules.
Then run

```
composer install
```

and :

```
npm install
```

After that try to run these commands:

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan view:clear

php artisan route:clear

composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: Well I feel silly.  It was the artisan clear commands that fixed it.  I had done the installs but not the clears.  Should have realized.  THANK YOU!

Comment: Ywc buddy, It is not silly, Sometimes people make mistakes, Good luck